# Retrieving the the last non None value in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a a huge DataFrame with a lot of None values in many columns. I wonder if I'm interesting in one specific column, is it easy to get the "last" valid values from the other columns? I tried to setup an easy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None, 123],
                   [2, None, 11, None], 
                   [3, 13, None, None], 
                   [4, None, None, 124],
                   [5, None, 10, None], 
                   [6, None, None, 126]
                  ], 
                  columns=['id', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3']
                 )
```

Say that it is `value3` that is of interest, then I'm looking for the easiest way to get this data:

```
1, None, None, 123
4, 13, 11, 124
6, 13, 10, 126
```

Here I get the first row with a valid `value3` value and None for `value1` and `value2`. The second row is data from row 2,3 and 4 combined.

Comment: Just `df.ffill()` or `bfill()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `ffill` to get the last non-null value of the other columns, then combine it with the non-null values from the column you are interested in:

```
filled = df.ffill()

# The column you are interested in
col = 'value3'
result = df[[col]].dropna() \
            .join(filled.drop(col, axis=1)) \
            [df.columns.to_list()]
```